# Xargs/Curl/Grep Pipeline exits prematurely

Tags: curl, grep, xargs

I have this pipeline:

```
xargs -n 1 curl -b cookie.txt < URLs.txt | grep -Eoi "expr1|expr2|...|expr7" >> e:/Output.txt
```

And I can't figure out why it exits prematurely after processing every 50-60 links in the URLs.txt file. Could you explain where I went wrong?